# C++11 VS 2012 functor seems to choke when I have more than 5 parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

```
function <void ( int a, int b, int ia, int ib, bool rev, const Vector4f& color )> 
  benchTris = [&pts]( int a, int b, int ia, int ib, bool rev, const Vector4f& color )
{
}
```

The error is:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Tx>'
      with
      [
          _Tx=void (int,int,int,int,bool,const Vector4f &)
      ]
      main.cpp(374) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Fty=void (int,int,int,int,bool,const Vector4f &)
      ]
```

Works ok if I remove ONE parameter, for example `a` from the front:

```
function <void ( int b, int ia, int ib, bool rev, const Vector4f& color )> 
  benchTris = [&pts]( int b, int ia, int ib, bool rev, const Vector4f& color )
{
   // ok
}
```

Is there some parameter limit I don't know about?

Comment: There is a limit of 5 parameters in Visual Studio 2012 since variadic templates aren't supported

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: They just released 2013 preview 5 hours ago.

Comment: @JesseGood Groovy! (deleted my comment since it's mentioned in the linked duplicate).